# CurrentSiteManager via related model

Tags: python, django, django-managers, django-sites

Is it possible to use the CurrentSiteManager to check the site of a related object - not the site of the object itself?

So, given the following models:-

```
class A(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I want to use the following manager on B:-

```
    on_site = CurrentSiteManager('a__site')
```

Otherwise, I'll have to add site as a ForeignKey to both A and B and manage all the issues that come with that.

But it looks like the CurrentSiteManager wants the 'site' field to be on the B class, not on A.

Is my only solution to write my own CurrentSiteManager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) or related query name for this.

Comment: Could you explain how? related_name is for the reverse relation from A back to B, no? So I can do a.b_set (or whatever I define related_name to be) but how does that help me here?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think you want to make sure that the records of B that belong to a record in A are included in the same site? But that relation is already created implicitly via the foreignkey. I suggested the related_name since I assumed you were stuck on the reverse relation.